# In LabView using .net to design the user interface, the program does not respond when the button is clicked

Tags: .net, labview

[image]

The callback VI

[image]

After clicking the button

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to put the `Form->ShowDialog` invoke node into a frame by its own. At the moment your code shows the dialog while destroying the button and the event callback all at the same time, hence the crash when clicking the button.